# Spring configuration calling more than one method

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have code which looks like the following:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
context.start();
MyEntity entity =  context.getEntity();
```

I want to inject the MyEntity instance into various classes.
But I don't know how to setup my Spring configuration, where I first create an object, then call a method on it and then finally call another method which returns the entity I want to inject.

EDIT 2 - removed the Strings altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common type of dependencies injected using Spring don't depend on the user input for their construction. This includes data access objects, services etc.,

You are talking about injecting domain objects whose construction depends on the user input either directly or indirectly.

Spring provides [`@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) annotation to inject such domain objects that are created using `new` operator. You can search for "@Configurable Domain Driven Design" on the internet to get examples of how this can be implemented. I myself used it in one my applications and wrote a simple post [here](http://vikdor.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-configurable-to-inject-resources.html) that might help you get started.

**Edit**:

To create a bean of type MyEntity as per the specification in your updated question, you would need to

- define a bean of type MyContext
- Create a MyEntityFactory class that would depend on the MyContext bean.
- The factory method would take the MyContext bean as argument, calls `context.start()` on it and returns an instance of MyEntity.
- You would define the MyEntity bean using this factory class.

The MyEntityFactory class would be as follows:

```
public class MyEntityFactory
{
    public static MyEntity getMyEntity(MyContext context)
    {
        context.start();
        return context.getEntity();
    }
}
```

The spring bean configuration will be as follows:

```
<bean id="myContext" class="FQCN.Of.MyContext" />
<bean id="myEntity" class="FQCN.Of.MyEntityFactory" factory-method="getMyEntity">
    <constructor-arg ref="myContext" />
</bean>
```

Since `MyEntity` is a singleton bean, the factory method will be called only once, btw.

More on creating beans using factory methods [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The Strings are constant. See edited question.

Comment: If they are constant strings, then what is the point in passing them as arguments to constructor? You can as well refer to them directly where needed. Once that is done, then all these objects are no different from processing elements like DAOs/Services. You can either explicitly define them as `<bean>`s in your application-context.xml or enable `<context:component-scan base-package="" />`, annotate them with `@Component`, and inject them using either `@Resource` or `@Autowired`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not that. What I don't know is how I can create an object, then call a method on it and then call another objects (as shown in code above). I can obviously do this in code but I don't know how to do it in Spring's application context xml.

Comment: Is the call to start method import to get hold of the `MyEntity` object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the word "import". But yes, if I don't call the start method, it will give me an exception when i call the context.getEntity()

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "important". Please see my update about the spring configuration and the code required for this.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Wonder why I did not think of that wrapper class.